# How can I check if the fb:like button is already pressed on my own page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have a website serving free mp3-downloads and I would like them to be only available for facebook fans of the fb-page of the website. The links are thus hidden unless the user is a fan.

I have reached partial functionality by subscribing to the `'edge.create'` event, but this event is not fired when the like box is loaded and the page has already been liked.

I don't really know what the best way to do this is, or whether it's possible at all without user permission. Most information on facebook forums is horribly outdated and a lot of it is related to on-facebook facebook apps/tabs, which is not my case.

To clarify: my facebook like button is on my own domain, in my own code.

Comment: Store it somewhere? In the php session, for example

Comment: sorry zerkms, I've edited my question cause I made some progress but now I notice your comment is related to something that's not part of the problem anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without user permission. You need to ask the user for the `user_likes` permission as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

Comment: That gives you permission to view ALL their likes - not just your page.  I think there's an easier way...